# How to add autocomplete to the follwoing Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to add autocomplete based on what the user searches.
Currently, I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "courts_2": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "author": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "bench": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "citation": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "standard": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "court": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id_": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "standard": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "verdict": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the code I used for the settings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_metaphone"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_metaphone": {
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "metaphone",
            "replace": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "author": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "bench": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "citation": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "court": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "date": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "id_": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "verdict": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "standard": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "standard": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I would like to implement: 
I would like to collect and store all of the queries made to the endpoint and use autocomplete on that. For example, to date, all of the users have made the following queries -

```
Real Madrid v/s Barcelona 
Real Madrid Team 
Real Madrid Coach 
Barcelona v/s Man City 
Sevilla Home Ground
Man Utd. recent results
```

Now, if anyone searches `Rea` then the following autocomplete queries should be suggested:

```
Real Madrid v/s Barcelona 
Real Madrid Team 
Real Madrid Coach
```

This based on the searches made by all of the users till date and not a single user. Further, I would like to analyze what are the top queries that were made in let's say the past month.

I am using ElasticSearch version 7.1 on AWS Elasticsearch service.

Edit: I have considerably digressed from the initial question as my need has evolved a bit. I apologise if this has caused any troubles.

Comment: Which field(s) do you want to implement autocomplete on? What is your use case?

Comment: Please provide the complete example including the setting of your index, which contains the definition of your `my_analyzer` and some indexed docs and expected output. Autocomplete can be implemented in various ways and completion suggestor reuires indexing your suggestions. if you are not constrained by completion suggetor, then I can suggest other alternatives which won't reuire re-index.

Comment: what version of ES are you using ?

Comment: @Val The ```title``` and ```content``` field.
@OpsterESNinja Please the edited question, I have added all of the info. 
@CatalinM. ```7.1```

Comment: @Abhijith thanks for update, so you just want the show users suggested queries on autocomplete or the actual results ? it would add a lot of value to your post if you can show ur sample input and output

Comment: @OpsterESNinja Sorry for not including that, I have now. Also, it would be great if you could re-read the question from the start as I have changed my requirement a bit. Hope it is not much of trouble to you.

Comment: @Abhijith any update on my last comment

Comment: Sorry for being late @OpsterESNinja. I just want autocomplete on the queries the users have searched before. I want to save (index) the user queries and based on that have to autocomplete. Sorry, but I did not understand the differentiation between results and queries?